# How to set browser tab title with route name in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web, browser-tab

currently in my app, the browser tab title is just the name of the screen. However I want to set the tab title to `{APP_NAME} - {PAGE_NAME}`. I am using a `<Stack.Navigator/>` and I know that you use the `screenOptions` to give a custom title, but I cannot access the `route` name.

```
<Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={Pages.HOME}
        screenOptions={{
          title: `MyAppName - ${route.name}`,
          header: ({ navigation, back, route }) => (
            <Navbar
              navigation={navigation}
              back={back}
              title={route.name}
              navigationOptions={[
                Pages.HOME,
                Pages.MY_MESSAGES,
                Pages.PROFILE_AND_ACCOUNT,
                Pages.MY_ACCOUNT,
                Pages.FAQ,
              ]}
              actions={[logoutAction]}
            />
          ),
        }}
      >
```

As you can see, the `header` param contains `route`, but I cannot/don't know how to get this into the title.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this for every screen. You can customize the document title in `NavigationContainer`

```js
<NavigationContainer
  documentTitle={{
    formatter: (options, route) =>
      `MyAppName - ${options?.title ?? route?.name}`
  }}
>
  {/* content */}
</NavigationContainer>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#documenttitle

Though also if you need the route name in options as mentioned in docs:

```js
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    title: route.name,
  })}
>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options/#screenoptions-prop-on-the-navigator